# Constants in Android xml file

Tags: android, xml, string

I have some code like this in my Android settings xml file (res/xml/settings.xml):

```
    <EditTextPreference
            android:title="@string/settings_date_format"
            android:summary="@string/settings_date_format_summary"
            android:key="settingsDateFormat"
            android:defaultValue="@string/config_settings_date_format_default_value" />
```

And a string like this:

```
<string name="config_settings_date_format_default_value">dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm</string>
```

As you can see, I'm setting the default value to a string. However, I'd like to have these default values stored somewhere else as it doesn't make sense to put them in res/values/strings.xml

Is it possible for me to put them in a new file called "config.xml" for example?

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense to put it in `strings.xml`?

Comment: I'm putting all of my user facing strings in that file, things that they'll see on the screen. Whereas the config settings are background things that they shouldn't have to worry about. For example, say I had a timeout config setting in milliseconds... if the user saw it it should be in minutes, so it makes no sense to group this sort of stuff in with user facing strings.

Comment: I get it, but the user is not aware of `stings.xml`. The user doesn't even know how your app is made. But in short, you can have as many xmls files with string resources as you want. It's up to you how you organize your information.

Comment: Thanks Merlevede. From the developer perspective, if we're changing the default config values regularly it is easier if it's put in its own config file. How can I create a new string resource xml file that settings.xml can read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add another XML file in the `values` folder and name it however you want.

On compilation time, the compiler will scan all your resources folders, regardless of the files and their names, and will create a lookup table for all your resources.

Comment: Even if I move the strings in config.xml, would I still have to call it with @string/my_string_name? Or could it be @config/my_string_name? Is there any way I can make it use `@config` specifically?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple files with string constants in them. You just have to follow the file naming rules and make sure not to duplicate any of the string or file names.

Comment: So if I create config.xml in the same directory as strings.xml, I can reference it in settings.xml by doing @config/my_string_name ?

Comment: No, you always use `@string/my_string_name`. The `string` keyword specifies that the resource is a string, the compiler will resolve and search in all your string files until it finds `my_string_name`.

Comment: Merlevede is correct. You can name the files differently, but the strings themselves still need to be defined as <string .../> elements.